# What is the electric field due a charged conducting sheet and a charged conducting plate in terms of $σ$ and $ε°$?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

I am getting it equal to $σ/2ε°$ for a conducting sheet and $σ/ε°$ for a conducting plate. Am I right? If yes then explain it to me why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

It is because the sheet chosen has no thickness,consequently charge isnt divided. But in between conducting plates, there is seperation of charge and field outside the plates is zero. In case of plate, charge is also doubled since material is present between two faces.
Using gauss's law.

1. For sheet:-
   $$|\vec{E}|=\frac{Q_{enc}}{2A\epsilon}$$
2. For conducting plates:-
   $$|\vec{E}|=\frac{Q}{A\epsilon}$$
   3.For just plate:-
   $$|\vec{E}|=\frac{2Q}{2A\epsilon}=\frac{Q}{A\epsilon}$$

Comment: In second case I am talking about the electric field due to a single plate in front of it? I am not talking about parallel plate capacitor in which there are two plates close to each other.

Comment: To @SaqibRashid :- I included that one too. Note that homework questions are disregarded on this platform unless they are asking about underlying concepts. Please try to add your attempt too or query to prevent your question from getting closed.